# Could not transfer artifact en netbeans con maven

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

¿Cómo se puede solucionar este problema en NetBeans?

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
Unable to parse element 'port', must be an integer (position: END_TAG seen ...<port>52.323</port>... @10:32) caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "52.323" @ C:\Users\jalva\.m2\settings.xml, line 10, column 32

Scanning for projects...

-------------------------< Tdea:CicloDoWhile >--------------------------
Building CicloDoWhile 1.0-SNAPSHOT
  from pom.xml
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  2.404 s
Finished at: 2023-09-29T13:16:09-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.3.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:3.3.1 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:3.3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to 127.0.0.1:0 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Agrega tu archivo C:\Users\jalva\.m2\settings.xml a la pregunta, creo saber el problema